# Python/Kivy - Button position

Tags: python, kivy

I'm a noob with using Kivy. 
As you can see, I created a simple window with a button. But why doesn't the button change to position to (200, 200)?

```
 def build(self):
    layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
    self.labela = Label(text=celotnobesedilo, font_size=14)
    gumb = Button(text='SEND', font_size=12, size_hint=(None, None), size=(200, 50), pos=(200, 200))
    gumb.bind(on_press=self.posljipodatke)
    layout.add_widget(gumb)
    layout.add_widget(self.labela)
    return layout
```

What is wrong? Button is shown, but always on position (0,0).
Tnx.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using BoxLayout, the position of the children of a boxlayout depends of his position,you can use a floatlayout instead, but if you don't want to change the layout then you can use the pos_hint property an example:

```
    def build(self):
        layout = FloatLayout()
        self.labela = Label(text='celotnobesedilo', font_size=14)
        gumb = Button(text='SEND', font_size=12, size_hint=(None, None), size=(200, 50), pos=(200, 200))
        gumb.bind(on_press=self.posljipodatke)
        layout.add_widget(gumb)
        layout.add_widget(self.labela)
        return layout
```

Comment: Tnx. I changed BoxLayout to FloatLayout (and import it of course), but now I get an error:
"TypeError: object.__init__() takes no parameters"

Why?

Comment: @JanezKranjski please remove orientation= vertical from the init of your layout like i've edited in my answer

Comment: Super, now it works (after removing "orientation"). 
I'm sure that I will have a lot of problems in the future, but ... there is no other way. My programmers work was more then twenty years ago (without any GUI of course).

Answer (score 0):

BoxLayout places its children in rows/columns. If you want to set a specific position of a child, use something like FloatLayout.